# grant to clone future object on Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, clone, sql-grant

i have grant on schema with future table as privilege to be cloned from another db/schema.

```
grant USAGE on schema <schemaA> to role <roleB>
grant SELECT on future Tables in schema <schemaA> to role <roleB>
```

with roleB, on another schemaB. the roleB can create object on schemaB.

```
create table db.schemaB.newtable clone schameA.newtable
```

i have yet an error authorization :

> Object SchemaA.newtable does not exist or not authorized

thanks for your help

Comment: was `SchemaA.newtable` created before you applied the future grants on schema A or after?

Comment: the table is  created after the grant.